# jQuery alternative to Adobe Edge Animate?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, adobe-edge

Here is my current situation.

I started using Adobe Edge Animate about 3 month ago and I both love and hate it. I love it because of how intuitive it is to create moderately complex animations and it has accelerated my workflow since I'm already familiar with Adobe products such as Dreamweaver, Photoshop and Illustrator. I hate it because as I learn more about it, I discovered how limiting it is for web developers since it has no built in support for server side code or even ajax. It also has a pretty heavy footprint.

I've been looking at jQuery plugins and have not found anything that could replace it. I mean such plugin would be a general purpose animation plugin, not one that would make a particular type of animation, such as a slider or carousel.

So, my question is whether such plugin exists.

If not I'm considering making one as an exercise, so any advice on how to implement a timeline, structure description system, trigger/action system and ajax/php integration would be welcomed.

Comment: It's going to sound like I'm purposefully being a jerk here, but I'm not, at least not too much.  If you learn jQuery (and CSS) really well, my guess is that you will see that you only need the things you say you need (timeline, structure description system, trigger/action system) if you are using Edge Animate.  That is, you want something to replace Edge Animate that is the same as Edge Animate, but without its flaws.  That's too much to ask for a jQuery plugin, and perhaps even jQuery itself, but you might benefit from some of the libraries in Ilan Biala's answer.

Comment: For simplistic animation like fade, slide, scale, rotate yes learning CSS and jQuery makes this easy.  But, much more complex animation like character animation and complex animation sequences, this isn't even remotely a good suggestion.  Edge Animate can most certainly do ajax calls to a server.  jQuery is loaded in the project so you can do anything jQuery can do.  You just need to know jQuery to leverage it.  But the overhead of edge animate is high, and Adobe is aware of this.  They are working on it is all I've heard.  I too want a substitute because EA is a good idea poorly executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of animations you are leaning towards, because a single jQuery plugin to cover every single type of animation would likely be more of a library and too big for most web projects at this time.

**[KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/)** is popular as an HTML5 Canvas framework that lets you create lots of animations, transitions, layers, and event handling which are some important things. I linked the site above so you can explore it a little and see what types of games/projects people have made with KineticJS and so you can get a feel of the type of animation for which it can be used.

Another animation library/plugin is **[CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/TweenJS)** which has a whole suite of content creation frameworks, the one you probably would be most interested in is TWEENJS, which supports some good stuff like CSS properties, and has a few sponsors already.

One drawback is that both of these animation frameworks are not based on jQuery but are based on JavaScript. This is good and bad because both frameworks don't depend on jQuery but you could probably use jQuery for get elements more conveniently.

Most frameworks are for JavaScript, but there is the standard `.animate()` method in jQuery that may be limiting compared to a full extended framework. It is more integrated into jQuery and you can animate the CSS properties though, so it all depends on how much you need and what you need exactly. Let me know if these don't suit you, and I'll try to find something different.

EDIT:

If you prefer something from Adobe, which it seems that you might, then take a look at [**Collie**](http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie/), which is another framework that uses the HTML5 canvas and DOM to create animations using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at google trends, I think I'll read more on KineticJS. If that doesn't suit me, I think I'll just keep practicing with .animate() until making animations is second nature to me. Maybe I'll write a simpler plugin to accelerate some tasks but nothing as heavy as something that will have all the Edge Animate functions. Just one question thought. The main reason I like Edge Animate is because of the interface. I know as a web developer, I should be writing codes, but that drag to build interface is so practical. Any application like that?

Comment: Not really, most of these frameworks that I linked are much more high-level and powerful, which means more of writing code and less of drag and drop because of its inability to provide every tool without all the clutter in an interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Adobe Edge Animate from months now too and I just love it.

> I hate it because as I learn more about it, I discovered how limiting it is for web developers since it has no built in support for server side code or even ajax.

I can't undestand what you mean here. Adobe Edge generates JS and CSS and HTML. If you generate them inside a project you can open it with the IDE of your choice. You can execute whatever javascript/jQuery you want.
You are not limited to write your code inside Adobe Edge.

Pesonally I use Adobe Edge only to bind functions to the UI events. 
For example, in the onClick event of a button I call MyApplication.myButtonFunction();
All the javascript is from external scripts.

So I develop in Eclipse and open up the .an project just to edit my GUI and animations.

I really think I'm missing something to understand your point...

Comment: I really meant built-in functionality. As you said, you actually had to get the code into Eclipse. Eclipse or other IDE features such as an internal server for PHP testing are not built-in. I know you can do everything by adding code yourself, but it feels like there could have been more.

Comment: I'm relativly new to web development and I want to improve. So please tell me: if you use jQuery to realize animations, what are the improved tools you can use. (I would post this on a private message but you can't do it here...)

Comment: I'm kinda in the same situation. Edge was a great tool, but I don't think I'll ever use it again. It taught me about element positioning and styles that I didn't even know existed like skew. I was able to experiment in an intuitive way so that my elements can be stretched, centered, moved with a flexible layout, etc... Now, I think I'll write a jQuery widget to do these kind of things.